# How to use ODBC(connection string) connection method in MySQL Workbench migration

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, mysql-workbench

now i try to migration a mssql to mysql by mysql workbench.

I created a local database. Then connect it via ODBC (native) method. Everything is ok. But when I try ODBC (connection string) method, the test connection always fail.

i dont know why, the connection string is copy from VisualStudio 2013's Server Explorer.
i try to add " wrap the connection string, but no work.

i want to migration my remote database, and i dont want to install mysql workbench to the server. what can i do ?

Answer (score 1):

The simpliest connection string is `Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;` and uses fields entered in the ODBC section of the control panel. If you want more connection strings example search the net or look [here](https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql/)

Comment: thanks @LHristov , i dont think my connection string was wrong, because i use it in my MSSSQL. i can not find any example about it use in mysql workbench, i want to know how to .

Comment: If running MySQL Workbench in Linux, this method gets you an alert box with "Test Source DBMS Connection" "Operation cancelled" - with no explanation of what is missing, went wrong, etc.  From what I can find with google, no one has ever made this work.